# I need this queue to also display the student ID as well as the name how do I fix this?

Tags: c, queue, structure

So I'm creating a program that will display a student's ID as well as their name in a queue. I've finally got it to work displaying the users name, but I also need the ID displayed as well. I'm afraid to start messing around to much and mess everything up. Someone show me the way to the light ;).

EDIT: Thanks to Paul R for pointing this out. I didn't realize until now that I'm only going to be able to display one letter at a time for my students name, what did I do wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct queueNode
{
    int data1; 
    char data;
    struct queueNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct queueNode QueueNode;
typedef QueueNode *QueueNodePtr;

void printQueue (QueueNodePtr currentPtr);
int isEmpty (QueueNodePtr headPtr);
char dequeue (QueueNodePtr *headPtr, QueueNodePtr *tailPtr);
void enqueue (QueueNodePtr *headPtr, QueueNodePtr *tailPtr, char value);
void instructions (void);

int main (void)
{
    QueueNodePtr headPtr=NULL;
    QueueNodePtr tailPtr=NULL;
    int choice;
    char name;
    int ID;

    instructions();
    printf("?");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    while(choice !=3)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            printf("Enter ID: ");
            scanf("\n%d", &ID);
            printf("Enter Name: ");
            scanf("\n%c", &name);
            //RETURN HERE TO ENTER LAST NAME
            enqueue(&headPtr, &tailPtr, ID);
            enqueue(&headPtr, &tailPtr, name);
            printQueue(headPtr);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (!isEmpty(headPtr))
            {
            ID=dequeue(&headPtr, &tailPtr);
            name=dequeue(&headPtr, &tailPtr);
            printf("%d %c has been dequeued.\n", ID, name);
            }

            printQueue(headPtr);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice.\n\n");
            instructions();
            break;
        }
    printf("?");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    printf("End of Run\n");
    return 0;
} 

void instructions(void)
{
printf("Enter your choice: \n"
            "1 to add to queue\n"
            "2 to remove from queue\n"
            "3 to exit\n");
}
void enqueue (QueueNodePtr *headPtr, QueueNodePtr *tailPtr, char value)
{
    QueueNodePtr newPtr;

    newPtr=malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));

    if(newPtr!=NULL)
    {
        newPtr->data = value;
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

        if(isEmpty (*headPtr))
        {
            *headPtr=newPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            (*tailPtr)->nextPtr=newPtr;
        }
        *tailPtr=newPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
    }
}

char dequeue (QueueNodePtr *headPtr, QueueNodePtr *tailPtr)
{
    char value;
    QueueNodePtr tempPtr;

    value = (*headPtr)->data;
    tempPtr = *headPtr;
    *headPtr = (*headPtr)->nextPtr;

    if(*headPtr==NULL)
    {
    *tailPtr = NULL;
    }

    free(tempPtr);
    return value;
}

int isEmpty(QueueNodePtr headPtr)
{
    return headPtr==NULL;
}

void printQueue (QueueNodePtr currentPtr)
{
    if(currentPtr==NULL)
    {
    printf("Queue is empty. \n\n");
    }
    else
    {
    printf("The Queue is: \n");

    while(currentPtr !=NULL)
    {
        printf("%c --> ", currentPtr ->data);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
    printf("NULL\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You students only have one character names ???

Comment: @PaulR wow didn't realize that I did that. What did I do wrong there?

Comment: Why are you `enqueue` separately `name` and `ID` Are you? `printQueue` and `enqueue` is not supposed ID to be passed as `value`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `char data;` (a single character) you want e.g. `char data[80];` (a char array, aka *string*). Ditto for `char name;`. You will need to use a string function such as `strcpy` to copy strings between your struct `data` field and your temporary variable `name`.